# Angularjs pdf viewer full screen view issue in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive, pdf-viewer

I am using angularjs pdf viewer in my project it is working fine with Google Chrome but while using it with IE when I go full screen by using full screen button in PDF viewer and press escape button it closes the PDF viewer expected behavior is it should close full screen mode and not the viewer, this functionality is working fine with Google Chrome. Not sure how to control this behavior

Any help is highly appreciated.

Just FYI, 
I am using IE 11.
The PDF file is being loaded from Server(Azure app service).
Server application is build in C#.net core

Here is my code

included in app.js

```
app.config(function(pdfjsViewerConfigProvider) {
   pdfjsViewerConfigProvider.setWorkerSrc("/pdf.js-viewer/pdf.worker.js");
   pdfjsViewerConfigProvider.setCmapDir("/pdf.js-viewer/cmaps");
   pdfjsViewerConfigProvider.setImageDir("./pdf.js-viewer/images");
   pdfjsViewerConfigProvider.disableWorker();
   pdfjsViewerConfigProvider.setVerbosity("infos");  // "errors", "warnings" or "infos"
  angular.lowercase = angular.$$lowercase;
});
```

included package

```
    "angular-pdfjs-viewer": {
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-pdfjs-viewer/-/angular-pdfjs-viewer-2.0.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-KnYVcp/UC9/01VVyY6aES4Mc=",
  "requires": {
    "bower": "^1.8.2"
  }
}
```

this is how I have included it in my page

```
<pdfjs-viewer data="$ctrl.data"></pdfjs-viewer>
```

controller

```
$scope.data = null; // this is loaded async
$http.get("http://example.com/file.pdf", {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(function (response) {
  $scope.data = new Uint8Array(response.data);
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain more details about the PDF viewer, whether it is a Third-party plugin? If you could post enough code or create a sample about the pdf viewer, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem. Besides, I have tested the [PDF.js Demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), it works well in IE 11 browser, you could try to use this library with your application.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pdfjs-viewer, it is working fine with IE but only issue is when I go full screen and press Escape key it closes the viewer itself instead I expect to close full screen mode only. Added some code to question. One more thing to highlight here is I can close the full screen mode by using F11 key.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check if there have some error in the F12 Console tab.

Based on [the document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pdfjs-viewer), I have tested [the angular-pdfjs-viewer demo](https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer/tree/master/demo), after downloading the package and installing the angular-pdfjs-viewer and related dependencies, it will show the following error in my IE11 browser:

`AngularJS: disabling automatic bootstrap. <script> protocol indicates an extension, document.location.href does not match.`

I tried to add the following code at the end of app.js file:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {  
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

After adding the above code, the error disappears.

Then, if I open the pdf in full screen mode by using the full screen button in PDF viewer, I could exit the full screen mode by clicking the ESC button. But, if I open the PDF in full screen mode using the F11 shortcut, I can't exist the full screen mode using the ESC key, it only exits by using the F11 shortcut. You could try to check it.

Besides, you could also try to clear the IE browser data (cache, cookie and so on) or resets the IE browser setting. Might be they can help to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried this but still my pdf viewer get closed after pressing escape button, My pdf viewer is embedded in Model popup, I guess that might be an issue but if that's the issue it should be consistent across all browsers It works fine with Chrome.

Comment: Agree with you. perhaps the issue is related to the Model Popup, I have checked the Bootstrap Modal popup and the JQuery UI dialog, after displaying the modal popup, if we click the ESC key, it will close the modal popup. Besides, I also test it in the Chrome browser, it will also close the popup modal when click the ESC key. Which kind of Modal popup are you using? Try to verify it.